# Finding index of table rows with checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table, clojurescript

I have a html table where the first cell of each row contains a checkbox. I would like to get the index of each row with a checked checkbox. I have access to JQuery as `js/$`

This is what I have so far, but it only returns Javascript object from which I cannot extract the index(es).

```
(-> (js/$ "#table tr")
    (.has ":checkbox:checked")
    (.find "td:eq(1)")
    (.each (fn [e] (.text (js/$ e)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Ozan's Javascript answer I was able to come up with this solution:

```
 (.map js/$ (-> (js/$ "#table tr")
            (.has ":checkbox:checked")) (fn [tr] (.index (js/$ tr))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with the syntax in the question, but this jquery code should be pretty easy to translate over.

- Get checked checkboxes using [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- Get `tr elements` containing these checkboxes using [`.closest(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector)
- Obtain the indexes of these tr elements using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index)

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var trs = $("input:checked").closest("tr"); //get tr elements of checked inputs
  var indexes = $.map(trs, function(tr) { return $(tr).index(); }); //make an array containing the indexes of these tr elements

  console.log(indexes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Get Selected Indexes</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution using ClojureScript :-)

Comment: I was just editing to mention it. I am not familiar with closurescript syntax, but this is pretty standard jquery code. It should be pretty easy to translate over.

Answer (score 0):

Ozan's solution works as intended for me, however, if I search for specific terms and select a row in the new rendered table (after filtering), the indexes I get are relative to this new table. To avoid this, I clear the filtering first, then use Ozan's answer. I don't think this is the best way but I put this here in case it helps anyone facing the same issue.

I use this line of code to clear the filters before to get the indexes.

```
table.search("").draw();
```